# use java in python 3.4 with nltk

Tags: java, python, nltk

I want to use stanford-tagger in my project but below error is occur.

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 59, in tag
    return self.tag_sents([tokens])[0]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\hazm\POSTagger.py", line 25, in tag_sents
    return super(stanford.POSTagger, self).tag_sents(refined)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 64, in tag_sents
    config_java(options=self.java_options, verbose=False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 82, in config_java
    _java_bin = find_binary('java', bin, env_vars=['JAVAHOME', 'JAVA_HOME'], verbose=verbose, binary_names=['java.exe'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 544, in find_binary
    binary_names, url, verbose))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 538, in find_binary_iter
    url, verbose):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 517, in find_file_iter
    raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.
===========================================================================
```

NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.

please help me for set java variable. i use windows 8 64 bit and python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the Java documentation for setting your path.](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

## Windows 8

- Drag the Mouse pointer to the Right bottom corner of the screen
- Click on the Search icon and type: Control Panel
- Click on -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
- Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
- In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the * value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
- Close the window.
- Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

Comment: [You're welcome Hassan. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if this solved your problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)

Answer (score 2):

Add it to your code:

```
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
```

Answer (score 0):

your nltk library can't find the java directory in your computer.

go to nltk library files in your venv and find `internals.py` in files
find this line in the code:

```
def config_java(bin=None, options=None, verbose=False)
```

change the code like this:

```
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_281/bin/java.exe" #your java file address
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
def config_java(bin=java_path, options=None, verbose=False):
...
```